# Zend framework 1.12 - Hash Form Validation returns error

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I am using Zend_Form_Element_Hash to protect csrf on my website. Below is the code in my Form.php

```
$token = new Zend_Form_Element_Hash('token', 'csrf');
$token->setSalt(md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)));
$token->initCsrfToken();
$token->initCsrfValidator();
$this->addElement($token);
```

When I check for $form->isValid in my controller I always get the below error

```
The two given tokens do not match
```

Would appreciate any help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Csrf is stored in session, session name for csrf depends on salt. If
   salt is random, session name will be random too. So you couldn't get
   csrf from session to compare it with csrf from post. Make salt
   constant for this form.
2. Don't call `initCsrfToken`, this method resets csrf and is called
   automatically on render.
3. Better transmit salt on element creation

   ```
   $token = new Zend_Form_Element_Hash('token', 'csrf', array('salt' => 'secure'));
   $this->addElement($token);
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Max I will try this out!